# Give a partition to a dataframe and fill every piece with a specific value

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a spark data frame `df` (`df` has a column `id` which has unique values) and a `partition_df` data frame which contains a `percentage` and `value` column, i need to create a new column for `df`, say `value2`, and assign it the value contained in `value` to a proportional number of rows of `df` given by `percentage` in the `partition_df`

For example:

```
df
+----+----+
|id  |col2|
+----+----+
|a   |3   |
|b   |1   |
|ab  |4   |
|z   |1   |
+----+----+

partition_df
+----------+-----+
|percentage|value|
+----------+-----+
|50        |asdf |
|25        |qwer |
|25        |zxcv |
+----------+-----+
```

I need to fill the 50% of rows (the chosen rows can be random) of `df` with "asdf", 25% of the rows (non overlaping) with "qwer", and the remaining rows with "zxcv", a possible answer could be

```
+----+----+------+
|id  |col2|value2|
+----+----+------+
|a   |3   |asdf  |
|b   |1   |qwer  |
|ab  |4   |zxcv  |
|z   |1   |asdf  |
+----+----+------+
```

My initial idea is to create a scala `Seq` containing the data in `partition_df`(that dataframe is super small, at most 10 rows), say `partition_seq`, split the dataframe containing only ids (i.e. partition `df.select("id")`) using `randomSplit` and the weights in `partition_seq`, that gives me the ids of the partitions, then iterate the partitions and add the column with the value stored in `partition_seq`.

I think that this is gonna work but i feel that there should be a better way (that is, a more elegant "spark way") to solve this, maybe you can give me an idea.